# How does collecting mouse movements increase cryptographic strength?

Tags: encryption, key-generation

Excuse me if this is obvious, but while encrypting one of my disks, I got bored and read the text on the window.

[image]

And the question came to me, how the heck can I move a mouse in a way that a computer couldn't reproduce?

To be more specific, what information does me moving my mouse provide that VeraCrypt couldn't make itself? Further, How much do these mouse movements matter?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are you doing when you move your mouse randomly during a truecrypt volume creation?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/10438/what-are-you-doing-when-you-move-your-mouse-randomly-during-a-truecrypt-volume-c)

Comment: @SuperStormer Yep!